# XPages Pager with Last and lots of pages

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am looking at a way to bypass a bug in the standard pager with views that contain a large numbers of documents.  When I use the code below, the "Last" won't show up:

```
<xp:this.facets>
    <xp:pager layout="First Previous Group Next Last" xp:key="header"
        id="pager1" for="myView" partialRefresh="true">
</xp:pager>
```

Anyone got around this, or has an alternate solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `alwaysCalculateLast` property on the xp:pager to true to calculate the last document in the view. There can be a performance hit when this is set to true, though.

Comment: I thought this was only for the extension libray pagers...  Just looked and it is part of the properties section in Designer 9.0.1FP10...   Didn't see that before  ;)